# How to initialize a 2D array with variable size without using pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I want to initialize a 2D array size say a[x][y] where I will be taking x and y as inputs. 
Is this possible? Because I guess you need a constant integer to initialize an array.
Cheers.

Comment: [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) i.e `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in definition of array you must use number, you can't define an array with dynamic size; it is limitation of array.

but you can use new and advanced data structures like vector,list,map,set,...

Comment: How can I use maps? Any reference links?

Comment: @AnandAkshay www.cppreference.com . or preferably learn from a book